# Nessus is reporting false positives for Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, security

We've recently added some new Debian 12 servers to our usual Centos/Rocky estate, and Nessus is scanning via ssh and is reporting critical vulns on our Debian vms.

However, the systems are patched up to date (using all the stable repos) and the version reported by apt appears to include the security patch.

Eg, a samba critical vulnerability reported by Nessus today requires this package, libldb2:

**libldb2_2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1**

This is what's installed and the most recent available from Debian's repos:

**libldb2_2:2.6.2+samba4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1**

As you can see, Debian's version naming appears to include the fixed version "4.17.12" as a suffix, but Nessus doesn't appear to recognise this.

I assume this is a basic pattern matching issue by Nessus, and given Nessus and Debian's widespread use, is bound to have been solved before.

Can anyone please tell me how to get Nessus to recognise Debian's versioning and not report false positives?

Comment: Can you add a link to the CVE?

Comment: Certainly - the DSA is here, which contains links to multiple CVEs. 

https://www.debian.org/security/2023/dsa-5525

Comment: It's been years since Ive had to deal with Nessus scans, but false positives due to OS's patching old versions was super common.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Happens sometimes. Either contact their tech support and escalate, or report from within the product itself. I know that Vulnerability Management (which uses Nessus) can do that from the recast/accept (under accept) window, where you have a slider to report a FP to Tenable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, Nessus Pro doesn't appear to have any way to report from within the app - or at least I can't find it. 

Their forum says they require a support case to be opened for all plugin bug reports. I don't have access to our corporate account to do this, and I've now run out of justifiable time trying to report a bug that should be easy to do.  

The bug still exists today.

Shame that Nessus make this so hard.